# How to build production application using sencha cmdv3

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell me how to build a production application using sencha cmdv3.

I have tried using

```
C:\Users\Test\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.0.0.250>sencha create jsb -a D:\Test
VSSProject\app1\index.html -p Test.jsb3
```

And I'm getting `no such property` error.
I also tried:

```
C:\Users\Test\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.0.0.250>sencha app build
```

And I get the error:

```
 Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application


C:\Users\Test\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.0.0.250>sencha -sdk D:\sencha-touch\
ext-4.1.1a app build production D:\Test
```

Thanks

Comment: if you have generated your app using [tag:sencha-cmd], you can just execute `sencha app build` then `sencha app build production`.

Comment: @rui I am using sencha cmd v3  can you provide full command where to give project name

Comment: @rui I am using sencha cmd v3  can you provide full command where to give project name

Comment: if you'll be executing that command, it will really cause an error. please check [this sencha thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259491-Why-sencha-creat-jsb-doesnt-work).

Comment: @rui my sencha command is install in c drive and my project is located in d drive how to map project with sencha command.I have tried with this command 
C:\Users\Test\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.0.0.250>sencha -sdk D:\sencha-touch\
ext-4.1.1a app build production D:\Test

Comment: when you'll execute `sencha app build`, make sure you are on your project directory.

Comment: @rui when i am in project directory in command prompt  sencha is not recognized command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36098/discussion-between-mohan-and-rui)